# Make an optional input parameter in QGIS Processing Algorithm Script

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

My version of QGIS is 2.8.3

I have a tool which takes parameters like this:

```py
##Input_Vector_Layer=vector
##Input_Raster_Layer=raster
##Distance=number 1.0
##Height=field Input_Vector_Layer

# Do Something...
```

Is it possible to make the fourth parameter optional?

Comment: Have you tried `##Height=optional field Input_Vector_Layer`?

Comment: Just tried but did not work, it gives me this :
'Problem with line: %d', 'ScriptAlgorithm') % (self.descriptionFile, line))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @user80597, did my solution work for you?

Comment: @HowToInQGIS It does work, though it is not the exact thing I am look for, I think this might be the best I can do in v2.8...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not a problem for you, my idea is to add a `Boolean`:

```py
##Input_Vector_Layer=vector
##Input_Raster_Layer=raster
##Distance=number 1.0
##Height=field Input_Vector_Layer
##Use_Optional_Field=Boolean True
```

and the directly check for its value:

```py
check = Use_Optional_Field
if check:
    # Do something...
else:
    # Do something else
```

Comment: This is probably the best method to emply using QGIS 2.8 =)

Comment: As suggested by @Joseph , the `optional field` parameter only works for more recent versions.